# What's the best way to migrate from preview version of .NET Core to the latest version?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, migration

I have a site built in .NET Core 1.0 Preview 2. It's using the deprecated xproj file. I need to migrate the project to the lastest .NET Core 3.1.

Would it be simpler to try and go through all the migration steps listed below for each new version one at a time or would it be easier to try creating a new site in 3.1 and trying to just move my code over?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

If the better answer is go through each migration one at a time, there are there any good walkthroughs on migrating from the preview version to .NET Core 1.0?

Comment: I would suggest you should do step by step migration then you will also understand the changes from one version to another.

Comment: OK, sounds legit.  How about any good documentation from going from 1.0 Preview 2 to 1.0?